# Show "if $f\geq0, f\in\mathscr{L}^2$ then there is $\{g_n\}$ continuous such that $\|f-g_n\|\to0$" implies the same for all $f\in\mathscr{L}^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> $\mathit{11.38}$ $\ \ $**Theorem** : The continuous functions form a dense subset of $\mathscr L^2$ on $[a,b]$.
> More explicitly, this means that for every $f \in \mathscr L^2$ on $[a,b]$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a function $g$, continuous on $[a,b]$, such that
> $$
> \|f-g\| = \left\{\int_a^b |f-g|^2 dx\right\}^{1/2} < \epsilon
> $$
> **Proof** $\ \ $ We shall say that $f$ is approximated in $\mathscr L^2$ by a sequence $\{g_n\}$ if $\|f-g_n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $A$ be a closed subset of $[a,b]$ and $K_A$ its characteristic function. Put $$
> t(x) = \inf |x-y| \quad (y \in A)
> $$
> and $$
> g_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+nt(x)} \quad (n = 1,2,3,\ldots)
> $$
> Then $g_n(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $g_n(x) =1$ on $A$, and $g_n(x) \to 0$ on $B$, where $B = [a,b] - A$. Hence $$
> \|g_n - K_A\| \leq \left\{\int_Bg_n^2dx\right\}^{1/2} \to 0
> $$
> by Theorem $11.32$. Thus characteristic functions of closed sets can be approximated in $\mathscr L^2$ by continuous functions. By $(39)$, the same is true for the characteristic function of any measurable set, and hence also for simple measurable functions. If $f \geq 0$ and $f \in \mathscr L^2$,let $\{s_n\}$ be a monotonically increasing sequence of simple non-negative measurable functions such that $s_n(x) \to f(x)$. Since $|f-s_n|^2 \leq |f|^2$, Theorem $11.32$ shows that $\|f-s_n\| \to 0$.
> **The general case follows.**

**My Question**: I followed everything except for the *bold* text. *How exactly does the $f\geq 0$ case imply the general case where $f$ is any function in $\mathscr{L}^2$ on $[a, b]$*?

**My Attempt**: If $f(x)\geq0$, then there exists a monotonically increasing sequence of simple nonnegative measurable functions $s_n(x)\to f(x)$ such that $\|f-s_n\|\to 0$. That means for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f-s_n\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. Recall in the proof it is said that simple measurable functions can be approximated in $\mathscr{L}^2$ by continuous functions, thus we can find a continuous function $g\in\mathscr{L}^2$ such that $\|g-s_N\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then $\|f-g\|\leq\|f-s_N\|+\|s_N-g\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$, as desired.

Now suppose $f\in\mathscr{L}^2$ is arbitrary. **Screeching halt**.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can write $f=f_+ - f_-$ as the difference of two nonnegative functions $f_+=\max\{f, 0\}$ and $f_- = \max\{-f, 0\}$ and apply the approximation on both of these nonnegative functions.

Comment: The substance of the question is entirely copied in the post.  You yourself ask a problem statement question that takes up only two lines of text.  Please study the post [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C128.3335), then return to edit and improve your question.

Comment: @amWhy I provided a bit more detail in post, please review. The reason that I omitted the details initially is because they do not pertain to the question I intended to ask; but what I failed to realize is that without those details, the post then became one of the "no clue" questions that are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function $f: X \to \mathbb{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}$ can be written as $f= f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+ = \max(f,0) \geq 0$ and $f^- = max(-f,0) \geq 0$. Then approximate the pieces. This is a standard trick used in measure theory. If $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-valued then you break up Re(f) and Im(f) further.